# exception while running drool sample program

Tags: drools

I am new to drools.I tried to execute sample program.I m gettng these exceptions

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/event /KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager
   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.drools.event.KnowledgeRuntimeEventManager
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Your classpath is missing drools libraries. drools-api

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response.Can you please refer me complete steps for installation of plugins and necessary jars for drools and guvnor in eclipse from scratch.

Comment: Google search "install drools in eclipse" first link: http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/droolsjbpm-introduction-docs/html/ch03.html